# Bibliography using the Harvard System

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I am using the Harvard System to write my references in my article. So I have the file "test.bib" which is considered a database and contains all my references. I will give you a very simple example in order to get your helps.

Firstly, consider my tex file: **my_file.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{harvard}

\begin{document}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

 author1 et al. (2005) proposed a new algorithm ....
 A new algorithm has been proposed (authors et al., 2005)
 author5 and author6 (2003) proposed a sophisticated algorithm...
 A sophisticated algorithm has been proposed (author5 and author6, 2003) 

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
{\small
\bibliography{test}}

\end{document}
```

Consider my file: **test.bib**

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{ x1,
  AUTHOR =       "  author1, C.  and author2, F. and author3, N. and author4, M.",
  TITLE =        "title1",
  BOOKTITLE =    "IEEE....",
  YEAR =         "2005",
  file = F
}

   @INPROCEEDINGS{ x2,
      AUTHOR =       "  author5, C.  and author6, F.",
      TITLE =        "title2",
      BOOKTITLE =    "IEEE....",
      YEAR =         "2003",
      file = F
    }
```

Consider the four phrases below and which are added to the article:

```
1) author1 et al. (2005) proposed a new algorithm ....
2) A new algorithm has been proposed (authors et al., 2005)
3) author5 and author6 (2003) proposed a sophisticated algorithm...
4) A sophisticated algorithm has been proposed (author5 and author6, 2003)
```

I know how to add the references manually into the text (such as author1 et al. (2005),  etc.), but how can I add them automatically? can I use for `\cite{}` for example? If yes, so how. Please I want the code in latex which can generate the for examples (the four phrases).

Kindly any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not load either the `harvard` or the `apalike` citation management package. Instead, I would load the `natbib` citation management package and use its macros `\citet` and `\citep` to generate text-style and parenthetic citation callouts. An important advantage of using `natbib` is that its fully compatible with the `hyperref` package.

Do keep loading the `apalike` bibliography style.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{ x1,
  AUTHOR =       "Author1, C.  and Author2, F. and Author3, N. and Author4, M.",
  TITLE =        "Title1",
  BOOKTITLE =    "IEEE....",
  YEAR =         "2005",
  file = F,
}

   @INPROCEEDINGS{ x2,
      AUTHOR =       "Author5, C.  and Author6, F.",
      TITLE =        "Title2",
      BOOKTITLE =    "IEEE....",
      YEAR =         "2003",
      file = F,
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}  %% just for this example

\section{Introduction}

\citet{x1} proposed a new algorithm.

A new algorithm has been proposed \citep{x1}.

\citet{x2} proposed a sophisticated algorithm.

A sophisticated algorithm has been proposed \citep{x2}.


\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```